# Trying to make haskell warp-tls authenticate the client

Tags: authentication, haskell, client, tls1.3, haskell-warp

I'm trying to make a https server that authenticates the client but it serves `curl --verbose --cacert ca.crt https://localhost:3443` successfully. I think it should reject for lack of client creds and require `curl --verbose --cert client.crt --key client.key --cacert ca.crt https://localhost:3443`. Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators #-}

module MockServerMain where

import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai.Handler.WarpTLS
import Servant
import Network.TLS

type MyApi = Get '[JSON] String

api :: Proxy MyApi
api = Proxy

server :: Server MyApi
server = return "Hello from Haskell!"

app :: Application
app = serve api server

main :: IO ()
main =
  let
    stngs = mkSettings "localhost.crt" "ca.crt" "localhost.key"
    warpOpts = setPort 3443 defaultSettings
   in
    runTLS stngs warpOpts app

mkSettings :: FilePath -> FilePath -> FilePath -> TLSSettings
mkSettings crtFile chainFile keyFile = do
  let
      hooks = def
              { onClientCertificate = \_ -> return CertificateUsageAccept
              }
      tlsSs = ( tlsSettingsChain crtFile [chainFile] keyFile ) 
              { tlsServerHooks = hooks
              , tlsWantClientCert = True
              } 
   in tlsSs
```

I suppose the obvious explanation is that I told it to always accept in the `onClientCertificate` hook, but the docs say I'm not expected to validate. I know that the `tlsWantClientCert` is having an effect because if I comment out the hooks it fails. When I only used `tlsSettings` rather than `tlsSettingsChain`, the behaviour was the same: accepting the credless curl. I know that the certs are OK because I can make nginx do what this haskell server is supposed to do and allow curls only with creds.

What am I supposed to do with the CA certificate that I want this server to check clients against? This server isn't supposed to know the CA private key.

I think this is the root of the problem: where's the constructor taking `ServerParams`:

```
data TLSSettings
    = TLSSettingsSimple
             { settingDisableCertificateValidation :: Bool                                  
             , settingDisableSession               :: Bool
             , settingUseServerName                :: Bool
             }
    | TLSSettings TLS.ClientParams
    deriving (Show)
```